# How to calculate Standard error of Normal Distribution with given Confidence Intervale

Tags: r, normal-distribution, excel

I have one basic question in preforming the forecast of fertility rate. I assumed if the fertility rate (is normally distributed) is equal to 3.0, there is an 80 per cent chance that fertility would be within one child(+-) of the mean. In other words, 80% of the change that fertility varies between 4 to 2 (mean=3). What is the standard error of the normal distribution in this case?

Answer (score 1):

If you had a normal distribution with s.d. of 1 and mean 3, 80% of data would lie within 1.718 and 4.282, i.e. within 3 +/-1.282 (r command: qnorm(0.9)). So you have to rescale the standard deviation to 1/1.282.

Answer (score 0):

Just to pick up on a small point hiding in @DatamineR's answer, you have used mixed terminology in your question. A theoretical distribution, like the normal distribution you are aiming to quantify, is defined by specified parameters and has a "standard deviation", which describes the spread of the data, not "standard error". The "standard error" is derived from real data and reflects the quality of an estimate, e.g. the population mean, accounting for the sample size.